# Resize UITableViewCell Height based on UILabel Content

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, swift2

I've been looking into this for over a day now, and I can honestly say I am completely stumped by why this is not working as I would expect it to.

I'm trying to have a UITableViewCell expand when selected to the correct size based on the UILabel within it. I have used the following code to determine the required size for the UILabel:

```
extension UILabel {

    func requiredHeight() -> CGFloat{

        let label:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.width, CGFloat.max))
        label.text = self.text
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.font = self.font

        label.sizeToFit()


        print("Final Size - \(label.frame.height)")
        return label.frame.height + 10
    }
}
```

My issue is, despite this size - when the Cell is resized within the 'heightForRowAtIndexPath' method - it is still not the correct size and the string is being truncated, this can be seen in the below image.

[image]

To note - I gather the required size of the cell as soon as the view has loaded and text has been populated into the UILabel.

```
requiredHeight = overviewLabel.requiredHeight()
        if requiredHeight > overviewCell.frame.height {
            expander.hidden = false
        } else {
            expander.hidden = true
        }
```

Any advice on how this could be fixed will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this snippet. Just provide exact name of the font and size

> **Swift 3.x**

```
func requiredHeight() -> CGFloat{
    let font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 16.0)
    let label:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:200, height:CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
    label.font = font
    label.text = self.text
    label.sizeToFit()
    return label.frame.height + //Add some space as a part of your bottom and top constraint
}
```

> **Swift 2.2**

```
func requiredHeight() -> CGFloat{
    let font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 16.0)
    let label:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, CGFloat.max))
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
    label.font = font
    label.text = self.text
    label.sizeToFit()
    return label.frame.height + //Add some space as a part of your bottom and top constraint
}
```

Suppose your label has top and bottom constraint as 5 and 5 respectively, them make the return statement as

```
return label.frame.height + 10
```

**NOTE**:- Width should be the width you want of the label. It should be according to your `UITableView` or `UIView`

Comment: Oh wow, it was that simple. May I ask, however, why does it require a font to be manually defined? I find it extremely weird I am unable to use `label.font=self.font`

Comment: I was also once caught in the same problem. May be some weird problem that label.font = self.font is not working. I searched somewhere that just provide the exact font and size of what your UILabel is using with little padding of constraints. Atleast that worked for me, How about you?

Comment: Yeah, it worked just fine thanks! I was just messing about with your snippet a bit more, and apparently the main reason mine was not working was due to my CGRect Width being set to `self.frame.width`. I do find this really odd as to why it happened. Thank you ever so much though.

Comment: If it worked for you, please accept the answer. thanks